# Measure size of libraries in Linux

Tags: linux, embedded, ram, rom

I'm developing S/W for some device which uses Linux O.S.
So, the size of libraries (RAM/ROM) which I use is very important.

How can I easily calculate RAM / ROM required by my software? (including libraries I used).
I think it's too easy question for experienced Linux developer.

Comment: This is in fact a difficult question. If your program uses dynamic memory allocation `malloc` or has nontrivial call patterns (especially if it has recursion), it's impossible even theoretically to predict how much RAM will be needed for the heap/stack. There are analyzers that work reasonably well at determining the stack requirements for typical embedded programs, but they often don't come cheap.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Run

```
size <object>
```

or

```
size <archive>
```

or

```
size <shared-object>
```

. (or "target-"size in case you're cross-compiling: arm-size if you're using arm-gcc)

It will give you a

```
text    data     bss     dec     hex filename
```

table where text is program-size, bss the initialized globals and data the read-only data.

While this answers your question, you probably will want to use a specific LdScript (when using ld as linker) where you will place the sections into the available memories manually when doing the final link.

Comment: Note that this tool only displays the static memory.  Run-time memory use will be larger.  How much larger depends on the program and it's use of the stack and heap.

Comment: Also can use "ldd" to check shared libraries. With "ldd" and "size", I can guess how much ROM/RAM used including libraries.